# Save the values of a dropdown in a String

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown for the user to introduce his/her birth date, but i don't know how to save it, in the model birthday is a String so I think i need to parse the three elements(day, month, year) or something like that, isn't it? I could not find any cleat example, any ideas? Thnx!

```
   <tr>
     <td>
      Birthday:
     </td>
     <td>
       <span class="savedvalue">@birthday</span>
       <div class="field-birthday field-return" id="birthday-edit" style="display:none;">
         <select id="day" name="day">
             <optgroup value="day">@Messages("views.profile.day"):
               @for( a <- 1 to 31){
                 <option value="@a">@a</option>
                } 
             </optgroup>
          </select>
          <select name="month">
          <optgroup value="month">Month:
           <option value="1">January</option>
           <option value="2">February</option>
           <option value="3">March</option>
           <option value="4">April</option>
           <option value="5">May</option>
           <option value="6">June</option>
           <option value="7">July</option>
           <option value="8">August</option>
           <option value="9">September</option>
           <option value="10">October</option>
           <option value="11">November</option>
           <option value="10">December</option>
         </optgroup>
        </select>
        <select name="year">
        <optgroup value="year">Year:</option>
        <option value="no">Prefer not to say it</option>
           @for(a <- 2013 to 1950 by -1){
             <option value="@a">@a</option>
            }
        </optgroup>
      </select>
     </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to get the value from the select element [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/1118218).

Then take the values from the three elements (month, day, year), and convert them to a date [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5619588/1118218)

I don't know how you are pushing the date back to the server, but doing this will convert your strings to a javascript date object.

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple, use jQuery date picker, http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Yep, but what when someone born in 1960 and has to from from 2013 until 1960, month by month..?